# Как для input type="number" задать минимальное значение не менее 30?

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно запретить указывать цифру менее 30, помогите реализовать данную задачу.
Спасибо!

Comment: такой вариант подходит? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9Lk67bn8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<input onchange="this.value = this.value<30 ?(alert('Минимальное значение 30'), 30): this.value;" type='number' min='30'>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: У меня кнопку отправить не нужно нажимать, если делать так, пользователь не поймет, что его значение не сохранено. Нужно делать так, чтобы было явно видно, что цифра не подходит.

Comment: Здорово, большое спасибо!